# Why aren't multiple NSSortDescriptors working with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have a controller with a UITableView which is displaying a list of "Item" objects, the items are like checkbook entries.  Everything seems to be working properly other than sorting.  I'll describe the sorting I'm looking for below, but currently the records are being displayed in the order they were created.  The Item objects (NSManagedObjects) have properties that include date (NSDate), amount (NSDecimalNumber) and entry (Entry is a NSManaged object that is a relationship to Item).

In the application you create an entry with a type (NSNumber 0 == credit, 1 = debit), title, description etc. Then you add 1 or more Item objects that have an amount, date etc.

I'd like the items to be grouped by date in table view sections so all the items that share the same date will be in the same section.  Within each section they should be sorted with first by type (credits first then debits) then by amount descending.  Something like this within a section:

### July 3, 2012

- Credit: 900
- Debit: (25)
- Debit: (15)

### August 7, 2012

- Credit: 1000
- Credit: 900
- Credit: 100
- Credit: 25
- Debit: (700)
- Debit: (450)
- Debit: (25)

The ViewController itself is a UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Here is the NSFetchedResultsController getter method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)aFetchedResultsController {

    if (_aFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _aFetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortType = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"entry.type" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortAmount = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"amount" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDate, sortType, sortAmount, nil]];


    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:@"day"
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.aFetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _aFetchedResultsController;

}//end
```

View Did Load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSDate *today = [NSDate new];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [offsetComponents setMonth:-1]; //1 month ago
    startDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];

    [offsetComponents setMonth:1]; //1 month ahead
    endDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];



    //set the MOC
    self.context = [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) managedObjectContext];

    [self fetchRecords];

}//end viewDidLoad
```

And the method that actually fetches the records:

```
-(void)fetchRecords{

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
    [[self.aFetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self aFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail

    }//end if


    [_tableView reloadData];

}//end fetchRecords
```

"day" is an Item instance method that I'm using to have the UITableView section headers display the formatted date string:

```
- (NSString *)day {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date];

}//end day
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sectionNameKeyPath:@"date"`? Or do you have two attributes `date` and `day`? In that case both must generate the same relative ordering. - Btw: What is not working?

Comment: updated question to include the "day" method's code and outline that the problem is that the records are being ordered by the date they were created, not my specific sorting scheme.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:`

> sectionNameKeyPath
>
> ... If this key path is not the same as that specified by the first sort
>   descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same relative
>   orderings.

This is not the case in your code. Converting a date to a string does not preserve the ordering.

There is sample code [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939) in the Apple Developer Library that demonstrates how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the code above all works perfectly and there really is no error with how the sorting is working.  The issue is obscured by my "day" function which is making UITableView sections based on the `NSDateFormatterFullStyle` representation of the the item's "date" property.  However the reality is that the dates are all different when it comes to the time portion which explains why they were being sorted by the order they were created.

I discovered this after trying Martin R's comment about using `sectionNameKeyPath:@"date"` and saw each row in its own section.

Thus the solution to my issue is to only set the month, day, and year of the "date" property when it is set, this may be unique to my application since those are the only portions of the date that I care about, not the time.

To do this I overrode the setter for "date" in my NSManagedObject "Item" with this code:

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                                    components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit 
                                    fromDate:date];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [comps setDay:day];
    [comps setMonth:month];
    [comps setYear:year];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:newDate forKey:@"date"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];

}//end setDate
```